# Mexican Cheese Sauce?

Tags: sauce, cheese, mexican-cuisine

There's a Mexican restaurant in my hometown that serves (their term) 'Arroz con pollo'.  The dish itself seems incredibly simple -- it's pretty much just rice, chicken, and an incredible cheese sauce.

I've spent countless hours on google looking for a recipe for something resembling this sauce, but there doesn't seem to be one definitive version of arroz con pollo, so I haven't had much luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what the sauce actually is?  What it looks like, tastes like, any ingredients you know of?  I don't think that you're likely to get a great answer without any more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's been a long time, and the place is 500+ miles away, so it's kind of difficult.  All I can definitively say is that it's creamy, nearly white, and delicious when served over rice/chicken.

Comment: i think you're referring to that sauce at mexican restaurants that should be served on anything anywhere anytime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sounds like a standard queso cheese (typically found on your chimis etc.)

If you are looking for a terrific queso recipe, there are myriad. However, two tips for any queso:

1. seek out "Chihuahua Cheese" (its a mild white that melts very smoothly and has a subtle flavor)
2. pepper and cumin and paprika roasted first are your friends, but if you add more than a little, they are your worst enemies. (also, fresh roast jalapenos for ideal flavor, don't use diced.)

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered calling them and saying "Hey. I live five hundred miles away, I love your cheese sauce, how do I make it at home?"

Comment: This is a nice comment. Sadly, I can't convert it anymore because the author's account was deleted. I am leaving it as an answer for historical reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Stuff like this is often highly regional, and even then different people will make it differently from house to house or eatery to eatery. I seriously doubt there even is a definitive recipe to be found. Considering that the name literally means "rice with chicken" and makes no mention of a cheese sauce, I doubt the traditional version of the dish has any sauce at all, let alone a specific cheese sauce.

If I were you I'd just start with a simple queso sauce and modify it to your liking. Beyond that, this site isn't a recipe exchange and posts seeking that are being closed.

Comment: Yeah. Try making a standard Mornay using queso blanco and see where that gets you.

Answer (score 3):

They probably don't do this, but if you ever want a nice melty cheese sauce look into adding some sodium citrate to the mix, it helps prevent the cheese from coagulating and gives a very smooth melty sauce no matter what cheese you start with.

Answer (score 2):

I have ACP in 2 differant mexican restaurants in the Avon Lake and Sandusky areas of Ohio.  They were awesome.  In both cases, I asked what kind of cheese they used, and both times the answer was white american cheese.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked two different Mexican restaurants what the cheese sauce was made of and they said melted white American.